# FolktaleJS Task.fork inside a function composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, task

Assuming the hypothetical ( and pseudo code below ) and I'm using FolktaleJS' data.Task monad, is there a way to call saveToDB.fork() and access the OBJ passed into saveToDB from getFromUI in the function composition? I realize this is far from decent practice but I'm trying to understand how this all works first. Thank you.

```
const Task = require('data.task')
const getFromUI = (data) => return data

const saveToDB = {
  post (OBJ) {
    new Task((rej, res) => {
      return db.save(OBJ) ? res(OBJ) : rej('failed save')
    }
  }
}

const postdata = composition(writeMsgToDOM, saveToDB.post, getFromUI)
```

Comment: Where is `saveToDB.fork ` defined? Do you mean `saveToDB.post()`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes! My bad on that one ....

Comment: Requirement is not clear. What issue are you having?

Comment: @guest271314 OK, not my day at all. saveToDB.post returns a Task which needs to be invoked with .post() ( saveToDB.post.fork ). However, I can't find a way to call saveToDB.post.fork in the postdate function composition. Rewriting the composition as const postdata = composition(writeMsgToDOm, saveToDB.post.fork( ... ), saveToDB.post, getFromUI) doesn't work. I also updated the OP to reflect Folktale's data.task is the responsible party

Comment: look at `task.chain`